# What is the earliest that a Cosmos Oracle can have access to the Decay domain and True Strike?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, oracle

I have a concept about a Cosmos Oracle operating in the frontline (taking advantage of the resistance to physical), rotting enemies with his touch.
Mechanically grabbing people in the first round, and if the victim still has not escaped by the second round, he will use [Withering Grasp](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=598) after True Strike.

For grappling I need high Strength, so I though to take a Champion Dedication with access to the Decay domain, this would also take care of the AC. However, [Divine Access](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1490) does not provide True Strike for Cosmic Oracles.
So the only option I see is Multitalented -> [some occult or arcane caster] then a Staff of Divination, but it takes level 9.

I found an Orc and an Android (and a 3rd I forgot) ancestry feat on level 5 that gives you True Strike, but it is only once per day.

I am fine with dropping Charisma, and taking only buff spells and pumping Wisdom, if a Cleric Dedication helps.

**How can I get Decay domain and True Strike (more than twice per day) before level 9?**

It has to be PFS legal, so no Evil deity, or free Archetype.

Comment: How set are you on the Champion Dedication (as in, can we grab the Decay domain from somewhere else)? And are you looking for a way that _doesn't_ rely on items (like the Staff of Divination)?

Comment: I am fine with another dedication, see my comment about the Cleric. I do not care about the source of True Strike, as long as it fits into 1 action (so no scroll with Trick Magic Item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Decay Domain

Easiest way to gain this as a Cosmos Oracle would be a Cleric or Champion multiclass archetype selecting a deity like [Kerkamoth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=140), The Waiting Void or [Shyka](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=100), The Many:

- [Cleric Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=694)/[Champion Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=686) - 2nd-level class feat
- [Basic Dogma](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=696)/[Basic Devotion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=687) -> [Domain Initiate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=265)/[Deity's Domain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=214) - 4th-level class feat

### True Strike

This is trickier, as of now there's no deity that grants either the Moon or Darkness domains that also grants *true strike* as a spell to be picked up with Divine Access. Should an option be printed in the future, then that would be an option as another 4th-level class feat to cast the spell using your oracle spell slots.

Other options include as you've mentioned being an Orc or Android to be able to cast the spell, or having the versatile heritage of [Aphorite](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=28) with any base ancestry and selecting [Offensive Analysis](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2482) as a 5th-level ancestry feat.

Humans are able to gain *true strike* through the [Adaptive Adept](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=73) 5th-level ancestry feat, after taking Adapted Cantrip as a 1st-level ancestry feat. Any other ancestry is also able to do this by taking the [Adopted Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=751) 1st-level general feat, though it may be tricky to do so before level 9 based on ordering.

You could also take the Dragon Disciple Archetype to gain *true strike* as a class spell with the following feats, though it would be difficult to do so before level 10 if you're taking a different archetype like cleric:

- [Dragon Disciple Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1940) - 2nd-level class feat
- [Dragon Arcana](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1943) - 4th-level class feat

Once you're able to Cast the Spell normally via some means, you'll be able to use something like *wands of true strike* (3rd-level items) or a *staff of divination* (6th-level item) to gain additional castings per day.

Comment: Adaptive Adept is the solution, thanks